# Make window.location.href load page from Server instead from browser cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, redirect

I am making a redirect using `window.location.href`.

But what it does, it simply fetches old page (not showing the newly added item) that was previously in borwser's cache.

I want it to fetch every think from server, just like we use `true` parameter in `document.location.reload(true)` to load a fresh copy of page from server.

Comment: can you show your code here?

Comment: its simply `window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com/products"`

Comment: if you think that it loads cached pages instead of new then you should try in `private browsing` to see the new result. other condition I can't examine what are you asking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com/products?t="+ (new Date().getTime());
```

Or:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com/products?t="+ Math.random();
```

Comment: Oh, my friend, you miss-understand the purpose ! This is not a gif/css/js file :D please read the article you have posted @CharlesAddis. USING QUERYSTRING **WILL NOT** PREVENT RESOURCES IN THE PAGE FROM BEING CACHED but JUST THE PAGE ITSELF! and THAT'S THE GOAL OF THE OP !! please remove the downvote !